# Leaflet GeoSearch: Google Provider not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I'm trying to incorporate search in my map using the Google Provider (I'm using [this (Smeijer/Leaflet-GeoSearch)](https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch) plugin with Leaflet), however I'm not able to make it work.
My code is very direct:

```
        const searchControl = new GeoSearch.GeoSearchControl({
            provider: new GeoSearch.GoogleProvider({
                apiKey: 'MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY'}),
            position: 'topright',
            style: 'bar',
            // provider: new GeoSearch.OpenStreetMapProvider(),
        });
        
        map.addControl(searchControl);
```

If I use the OSM provider (commented out in the code above), the search works fine (the results are kind of obsolete for my region, but it works) (Figure 1) . But if I use the Google Provider, nothing appears as a result of the search (Figure 2).

[image]

[image]

Some more details:

- Both the Maps JS API and the Geocoding API are enabled on the Google Console (BTW, for the GridLayer I'm using GoogleMutant which uses the API key and it's working flawless);
- The API key is not under any restriction in the Google Console, since I'm only testing this integration for now;
- The browser console outputs this:
  [image]
  I don't think it is related to this problem, but I guess it doesn't hurt to mention it.

Comment: This might have been caused by a set up problem. But ultimately, I don't think Google Maps APIs are designed for use with other mapping products. See: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:~:text=(e)%C2%A0No,non%2DGoogle%20map.

Comment: I'd suggest that you just use the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript) and its own [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-autocomplete) widget for better usability and compatibility if you want to keep using Google APIs itself.

Comment: @Yrll I'm already using the Google Maps JS API, at least indirectly, since the Leaflet plugins deal with the requests. Anyway, I'll have a look at the Place Autocomplete.